# how to display Pdf file from url inside android app

Tags: java, android

I am creating an Android app. How do I display a PDF file inside an Android from a url? without using already available system's pdf viewer application. Currently i am using webview and the code is:

web_view.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf_url);

but it is taking too much time to load and display PDF file. Is there any another fast way to do this.

Comment: you can use zohn zapata library

Comment: use this library 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.1.0'

Comment: Inside App .NO . You need to use some library for it . And AFAIK google doc viewer have some quota policy . So after sometimes it will give you error.

Comment: you can use this library AndroidPdfViewer https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Answer (score 5):

Do not use google docs, as it has limit. Best way is to use external PDF application installed on device. Loading and rendering a PDF depends on your network speed, processing capacity and file size.

You can use below code to load PDF in default viewer.

```
    public openPDFViewer(String url) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Error...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanku "Gokul Nath KP", i know its a good way to open PDF file, but when i m using the above code it closes my app for a moment and then open external pdf application. My requirement is to display the PDF file inside my app, as a part of it(with header and another contents available inside Activity).

Comment: Thanku so much, saved my day, Instead of using 3rd party library this is the best way for faster loading